# Preventing ListView column from resizing on double click?

Tags: c#

How can I prevent the column in a `ListView` from resizing to the length of its content when the right boundary of the column is double clicked?

Comment: If you develop your software for other people, maybe they want that feature as they know it from other applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `AllowUserToResizeColumns` property to false.